# $\gamma(t)=(t^2,t^3)$ is not smooth but then how come it has smooth components?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, curves

As far as I knew and as stated in this post [smoothness of multivariable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295926/smoothness-of-multivariable-functions)

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is smooth if and only if all of its components are smooth.

Consider a curve $\gamma(t)=(t^2,t^3)$ . This is just a multivariable function for n=1, m=2. But it is a well-know example of a curve that is not smooth, because $y=t^3, x=t^2$ yields $x=y^{2/3}$ is not smooth at the origin.  $\gamma(t)$ and $x(y)$ are the same function written in different ways, aren't they?

On the other hand the components of $\gamma$ are $t^2$ and $t^3$ which are smooth so **how isn't this a contradiction with the definition of smoothness above?**

Comment: It’s not a contradiction as they’re talking about smoothness of different objects. One is smoothness of a function (here a mapping $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$), while the other is the smoothness of the image set of such a function. Same word, different concepts, so no contradiction.

Comment: This issue is only compounded by the multitude of subtly different meanings for the word “curve”.

Comment: $x$ as a function of $y$ is not smooth. But $y$ as a function of $x$ [is](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kiz2egsyej).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ok, then reagarless of the notation, check if " $\gamma (t)=(t^2,t^3)$ is smooth" and "check if the curve  $\gamma (t)=(t^2,t^3)$ is smooth" are different questions.  What is the definition of smooth curve given that I can't use the definition of smoothness as a multivariable function? I just can't find a satisfying one.

Comment: like I said, there are many definitions lying around. I’m inclined to treat “smooth curve” to mean “smooth parametrized curve” which $\gamma$ certainly is (because the two component functions are $C^{\infty}$). If I wanted to specifically talk about the image set, then I would say that explicitly: the image of $\gamma$ is not a smooth 1D embedded submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Also, because of this very specific issue in language with curves I prefer to speak of “1D embedded submanifold” rather than the uninformative “curve” to clarify what I mean. Ultimately it comes down to context.

Comment: @peek-a-boo So this issue arised in the context of smooth manifolds, googling to try to figure out what is the definition that of smooth curve that I need to answer this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810001/prove-that-the-trajectory-of-the-image-of-a-3d-fixed-point-by-a-certain-parametr?noredirect=1#comment10232508_4810001. Would that be your definition in terms of submanifolds? Or is there a more direct and computationally friendly equivalent definition or way to do it? Feel free to answer there if you think is more appropriate

Comment: For a map, "smooth" means being infinitely differentiable. $\gamma$ is smooth. The map $\beta(y) = (y^{2/3}, y)$ is not smooth. These two curves have the same image, which makes them reparametrizations of each other, but the fact that $\beta$ is a non-smooth parametrization does not somehow disqualify $\gamma$ from being smooth. The common point set also is a smooth submanifold diffieomorphic to $\Bbb R$. It is only the one parametrization that is not smooth.